# Java based code that replicates Netstream and netconnection

Tags: java, android, flash, apache-flex, netstream

Is there a java api that allows you to use Netstream and netconnection functions from adobe? I'm working on my android app and I am trying to add a video chat feature on the app. Since the rest of the app is already coded in java it doesn't seem like I can attach a swf file to one of the activities. So I'm looking for alternative solutions to to connect with a web based flash video chat website from the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [JUV RTMP](http://www.smaxe.com/products.jsf) tool which is Java API to access RTMP servers. It also support audio/video streaming but you will need to provide the codec code.

*It is a paid product, but at least works fine. I could never find a good open source solution for this.*